# NuxtJs get value from input changed by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have an input hidden in nuxtjs, and value update by jquery after get query from url, I wrote this part with jq but look like nuxtjs not read and get value that set by jquery, it already return `null` after submit, but I want to get value that set by jq. But if I write on input it work fine and return value, but I want to return value on page load without any keydown by user.

**NuxtJs:**

```
<input v-model="requestObj.case" name="case" type="text" value="" id="ServiceCase"/>

data() {
    return {
        requestObj: {
            case: null,
        },
    }
}

methods: {
sendMail() { // this call when form submit
console.log(this.requestObj.case) // return null
}
}
```

**jQuery:**

I manged to update `value` only by `jq`

```
$('#ServiceCase').val(s).attr('value',s).change();
```

**Output:**

```
<input name="case" type="text" value="Burglary" id="ServiceCase">
console: null
```

**Desire Output:**

```
<input name="case" type="text" value="Burglary" id="ServiceCase">
console: Burglary
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to set your initial value in model, not in html. And dont use jquery. E.g.

```
data() {
    return {
        requestObj: {
            case: 'Bulgaria',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read question at all? I mentioned it, I set value by jquery based on url query string!

Comment: And? That still valid, you just need to get initial param from this.$route.query . Adding jquery is a way to make project unmaintable and it's should be done in 99.9% of nuxt projects